# Hudson jobs won't call javac?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, java, javac

I have just set up Hudson on my server. For some reason, my build will not call javac to compile my builds...? I have set the path to the JDK in the Manage Hudson area, and it seems to recognise it (doesn't give me a warning). Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Here's a sample console output of one of my jobs (note how javac isn't called at all):

> Started by user admin
>
> Checking out
>   svn+ssh://myhost.com/Project1
>
> A         /src/Program.java
>
> A        build.xml
>
> U
>
> At revision 119
>
> no change for
>   svn+ssh://myhost.com/Project1 since
>   the previous build
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Guessing your using Ant, since it points to a build.xml file.
If you have not already done so, you also need to configure the build target to run

Comment: It is an artifact of Netbeans. Do I have to use Ant for javac to be called? If so, how do I get Hudson to refer to a run target that is specified in my build.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ant-target for your build.
Since this is a netbeans project you should have ant target like: compile, default etc?

One or more of these build target must be set in your job on hudson under the configuration menu. I think the field is called "Targets"

Some information on configuring ant in hudson: http://testinfected.blogspot.com/2009/01/hudson-default-anth.html

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thanks. For some reason I just naturally assumed Hudson would compile Java projects itself, but you need to invoke Ant.